# How to implement integration testing for guards in nest js?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jestjs, nestjs

I want to implement unit testing for guards using nest js(Jest JS). I could nt find much documentation.

```
import {Test, TestingModule} from '@nestjs/testing';
import {CatsController} from '../src/modules/cats/cats.controller';
import {CatsService} from '../src/modules/cats/cats.service';
import {ICat} from '../src/modules/cats/interfaces/ICat';
import {JwtStrategy} from '../src/strategy/AppId.strategy';

  beforeEach(async () => {
     const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
             controllers: [CatsController],
             providers: [CatsService],
         }).compile();

    catsService = module.get<CatsService>(CatsService);
    catsController = module.get<CatsController>(CatsController);

  });
  describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should return an array of cats', async () => {
      // const appIdAuthContext: AppIDAuthToken = tokenInfo;
      const result: ICat = {
        name: 'test',
        age: 1,
        breed: 'one'
      };
      jest.spyOn(catsService, 'findAll').mockImplementation(() => result);
      console.log(result);
      console.log(catsController.findAll());
      expect(await catsController.findAll()).toBe(result);
    });
  });
```

The above code will return array of cats. i want to implement guards for this unit test.

Comment: Maybe this can help anyone https://stackoverflow.com/a/70825015/5160077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an implementation.i'm sharing the sample , it may help somebody

```
function createTestModule() {
      return Test.createTestingModule({
        imports: [
          PassportModule.register({defaultStrategy: 'jwt'}), CatsModule
        ],
        controllers: [
          AppController
        ],
        providers: [
          AppService, RoleGuard, JwtStrategy
        ],
        exports: [PassportModule]
      }).compile();
    }

beforeEach(async () => {
  const module = (await createTestModule(
    ));
  app = module.createNestApplication();
  server = app.getHttpServer();
  await app.init();
});

  it('Should create cat for admin', async () => {
    return await request(server)
        .post('/cats/createcat')
        .set('Authorization', catAdminToken)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .send(catDto)
        .expect(201);
  });
```

Comment: This not a unit test and more like an integration/e2e test.Please read https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html to understand different types of tests and see example of NestJs unit tests here https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#unit-testing

Comment: In the unit test, we don't instantiate the app module. We are simply looking to test the controller/service to check their basic functionality. What you have done is much more like an e2e test where we instantiate a test app.

Comment: Hey thanks for this answer, saved me a lot of time!