# NestJS mock JWT authentication in e2e tests

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, authentication, mocking, nestjs

I want to mock JWT Authentication in my NestJS e2e (integration) tests. I use injected token data in my business logic, and I don't want to insert credentials on my test code.

I implemented JWT authentication as per the [Nest authentication docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication). I use a decorator (similar) to the `@User` decorator in the examples, and use information on the User object in my business logic.

```js
@Post()
async myPostEndpoint(@Body() body: PostBody, @User() user: MyUser){
    // do stuff using user properties
}
```

When testing my application using supertest as indicated in the [Nest testing docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing), I don't want to make a real authentication request, as I would need to persist credentials in my version control system.

I expected to be able to override providers to return a test user. But couldn't figure it out.

I tried overriding the `AuthService`'s `validateClient` and `login` to return a default user using `overrideProvider + useClass/useFactory/useValue` as indicated in the [Nest testing docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#end-to-end-testing). I also tried overriding methods in `JwtStrategy` and `LocalStrategy`, but the requests still return 401 - Unauthorized.

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267536/testing-passport-in-nestjs

Comment: Unfortunately, the implementation in the accepted answer does not mock the user. Instead it does a real authentication request `.post('/auth/login')`, as I would like to avoid, since I would need to put credentials in my test code.

Comment: I think I added a `process.env.NODE_ENV` check in my auth code to handle the situation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your `overrideGuard(AuthGuard('jwt')).useValue()` you can add functionality to your `canActivate()` function to look like the following:

```
canActivate (context: ExecutionContext) => {
  const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  req.user = myCustomUserObject;
  return true;
}
```

Where `myCustomUserObject` is the expected value of `req.user` for the server to handle.

Comment: Hey Jey, I'm tried your answer, but I got "Cannot set property 'user' of undefined". The "req" value is undefined ... :(

Comment: I did the same, didn't get any error like @MirceaBaicu stated, but the next guard which registered on that API doesn't detect property _user_ on req, hence forbidden. Any clue why?

Comment: Why not use a test user and crate a JWT, I thought e2e tests should be close to the real application

Comment: Technically, that would be the better option @MADforFUNandHappy, but as the question was specifically about mocking the guard, I figured I'd answer with that.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying to mock the `AuthGuard` itself and it never worked.

Answer (score 16):

For people using GraphQL, this is what I did:

```js
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    })
      .overrideGuard(JwtAuthGuard)
      .useValue({
        canActivate: (context: ExecutionContext) => {
          const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
          ctx.getContext().req.user = { user_id: "abc123" } // Your user object
          return true
        },
      })
      .compile()
```

Answer (score 0):

some specific cases, we need to override canActivate dynamically (example, override different 'users')
so I just jest-mocked the 'jsonwebtoken' module like this

```
jest.mock('jsonwebtoken', () => ({
  verify: jest.fn((token, secretOrKey, options, callback) => {
    callback(null, {
      payload: {
        email: 'any@email.com',
        sub: 1,
      },
      header: 'header',
      signature: 'signature',
    });
  }),
}));
```